# Strike through text does not work with multiple cites

Tags: errors, text-decorations, ulem

I'd like to strike through some text in a paper with package `ulem`'s `\sout{}`. However, when the text to be struck through contains multiple cites like `\cite{a,b}`, the compiler gives some error messages like `Undefined control sequence`. I'm using the TeXLive 2014, and this problem exists for `latex` as well as `xelatex`. How to solve this without resorting to tikz? I do not like the cancel package with its sloping lines.

As an MWE,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ulem}

\begin{document}

Works: \sout{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet~\cite{a}}

Compile error: \sout{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet~\cite{a,b}}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{a} Paper a
\bibitem{b} Paper b
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use `\mbox{}`
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ulem}

\begin{document}

Works: \sout{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet~\mbox{\cite{a}}}

Compile error: \sout{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet~\mbox{\cite{a,b}}}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{a} Paper a
\bibitem{b} Paper b
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: answer would be more obviously valid with a visual.

Comment: nice idea to put the citations in a box! Thanks.

Comment: @touhami What for? :-). Any way, you are welcome. :-)